# How to generate a 3D graph from complex data?

Tags: python, database, 3d, plotly, complex-numbers

I have a function in python that takes a complex value of omega `(a + bj)` and returns me a complex Z value as well.

I want to generate a 3D graph whose axes are the real part of omega, `x = Re(omega)`, from the imaginary part of omega, `y = Im(omega)` (without the j) and an axis Z which contains the real and imaginary part of the function. In fact, I don't know if it's possible to plot the Z axis that way because it's complex. My first question is related to this, should I plot the module of the Z function compleza, or plot it in some other way?

Anyway, I tried to generate the graph as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

x = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
y = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7]
z = [(1.817013258458636+0.0017408694670920386j), (1.8135210458261364+0.0016586704636483481j), (1.81009723639075+0.0016222501419694648j)]

z_mag = np.abs(z).tolist()

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z_mag, x=x, y=y)])

fig.update_layout(title='Frequências',
                  scene=dict(xaxis_title='Re(ω)',
                             yaxis_title='Im(ω)',
                             zaxis_title='Resíduo'))
fig.show()
```

I truncated the lists and wrote them explicitly to be able to show the code without having to post the entire code which is too long. X and Y are already lists that have real values, according to what was said above. I plotted Z as an absolute value, but I don't know if it would be the best way to plot the complex value of the z axis.

The problem is that when I run the code, the result is an empty plot. What could be wrong? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is part of the [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) techniques. Complex numbers are characterized by an absolute value and a phase. We can plot the absolute value on the z-coordinate, and color the surface with the phase.

Here is an example showing the square root function over the complex plane. Notes:

1. I used `np.angle` to compute the phase, which returns values from `-np.pi` to `np.pi`, depending on the function being evaluated (range of 2*pi). Hence, this kind of plots are always suited to be used with [cyclic colormaps (or colorscales)](https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/#builtin-cyclical-color-scales).
2. Because Plotly uses a weird lightning which makes it difficult to understand the curvatures of a surface, I added wireframe black lines.
3. In this particular example, at `y=0, x>0` you see a discontinuity in the phase: that's called a [branch cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point).
4. I added `customdata` to the surface in order to show the value of the phase when moving the mouse over the surface: `customdata=arg.T`. The transpose is meant to "temporarly fix" [the following bug](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/5003), unresolved at the time of writing this answer.
5. depending on your function/data, you might have poles in it (points where the magnitude goes to infinity). If that's the case, you can apply a logarithm to the magnitude before plotting it.
6. Usually, domain coloring is done on 2D plots by applying different coloring techniques. I'm not going further into it, you can learn more on the above-linked wikipedia article.

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# number of discretization points
n = 101
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, n)
y = np.linspace(-2, 2, n)
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
domain = x_grid + 1j * y_grid
func = lambda z: np.sqrt(z)

z = func(domain)
mag, arg = np.absolute(z), np.angle(z)

fig = go.Figure()

# add surface plot of the magnitude, colored by the argument
fig.add_trace(
    go.Surface(
        x=x, y=y, z=mag,
        customdata=arg.T,
        hovertemplate="x: %{x}<br />y: %{y}<br />Abs: %{z}<br />Arg: %{customdata}",
        surfacecolor=arg,
        colorscale="mrybm", cmin=-np.pi, cmax=np.pi,
        colorbar=dict(
            title="Argument",
            titleside="right",
            tickvals=[
                -np.pi,
                -np.pi / 2,
                0,
                np.pi / 2,
                np.pi,
            ],
            ticktext=[
                "-&#x3C0;",
                "-&#x3C0; / 2",
                "0",
                "&#x3C0; / 2",
                "&#x3C0;",
            ]
        )
    ))

# add wireframe lines to better visualize curvatures
n_wireframes = 11
for x_val in np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), n_wireframes):
    domain = x_val + 1j * y
    z = np.absolute(func(domain))
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=x_val * np.ones_like(y), y=y, z=z,
            mode="lines", line_color="black", showlegend=False))
for y_val in np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), n_wireframes):
    domain = x + 1j * y_val
    z = np.absolute(func(domain))
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=x, y=y_val * np.ones_like(x), z=z,
            mode="lines", line_color="black", showlegend=False))
fig
```

[image]